# Laravel returns status ::35 - SSL Connect Error

Tags: php, laravel

I deal with a payment gateway provider and I have been facing a problem for days and I cannot solve it, the problem is simply that the customer pays after completing the order, arriving to the payment page (online banking) and the user may close the page of the bank after completing the payment process and do not click on the return button to the merchant page Here comes the job of the return url ( Enable Instant Payment Notification (IPN)) that the provider asked me to set up and I did, but the link sometimes works and often it does not work, when I asked the provider they said the error is:

**kindly be informed that we received message status ::35 - SSL Connect Error in most of the transaction.
In this case, please assist to have a check at your end for the mentioned error and client URL (cURL).**

I don't know where to go to check the curl as you see in my code there is no curl!! and Im using forge laravel so I'm not able to check the server log and even in laravel logs I can't see the error mentioned by provider

here my post url

```
public function getStatus()
{        
$vkey = config('services.payment.secret');// secret key
    $tranID = $_POST['tranID'];
    $orderid = $_POST['orderid'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $domain = $_POST['domain'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $currency = $_POST['currency'];
    $appcode = $_POST['appcode'];
    $paydate = $_POST['paydate'];
    $skey = $_POST['skey'];

    $key0 = md5( $tranID.$orderid.$status.$domain.$amount.$currency );
    $key1 = md5( $paydate.$domain.$key0.$appcode.$vkey );

    if( $skey != $key1 ) $status= -1; // Invalid transaction
    if ( $status == "00" ) {
    SavingPaymentAction::SendEmailAfterCharge($orderid);
    } 

    else { 
             SavingPaymentAction::SendErrorEmail($orderid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed by adding curl-ca-bundle.crt

Comment: where is this!?